# The DateTimePicker doesn’t accept date value from the DataGridView into the edit form

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview, datepicker

Every time I want to edit data, the DateTimePicker ignores or doesn’t accept the value from the DataGridView. 
I tried to debug it but it doesn’t work, the DateTimePicker remains the same, it doesn’t change the value base from the DataGridView.

[image]

Here's the code:
Code to open the edit form:

```
Dim editData As New AddData

 Private Sub editForm()
      editData.Options = "EditData"
      editData.load_leasee(leasee_id)
      editData.ShowDialog()
 End Sub

 Private Sub EditToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles EditToolStripMenuItem.Click
        editForm()
 End Sub
```

Code for the CellClickValue function and DataGridView1_CellClick:

```
Private Sub CellClickValue(ByVal selectedRow As DataGridViewRow)
        selectedRow = DataGridView1.Rows(index)

        editData.ExpiryDate = Format(selectedRow.Cells(15).Value, "yyyy-MM-dd").ToString() 'Expiry Date

 End Sub

 Dim selectedRow As DataGridViewRow

 Private Sub DataGridView1_CellClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellClick
       'Dim index As Integer
       index = e.RowIndex

       Console.WriteLine("index: " & index)

        If index > -1 Then

            CellClickValue(selectedRow)
        Else
            'Button2_EditForm.Enabled = False
            disableButton_InHome()
        End If

  End Sub
```

Code for the Edit Data form. The bug is here:

```
Public Property Options As String

    Public Property ExpiryDate As String


    Public Sub showInputs()
        Try
            '
            DateTimePicker2_ExpDt.Value = ExpiryDate.ToString() 'Ignores the value
            DateTimePicker2_ExpDt.Text = ExpiryDate.ToString() 'Ignores the value
            '
            TextBox4_ExpDt.Text = ExpiryDate 'Accepts the value
        Catch ex As Exception
            TextBox4_ExpDt.Text = ""
            DateTimePicker2_ExpDt.Text = ""
        End Try
    End Sub


    Private Sub loadOptions()
        Console.WriteLine("Options: " & Options)

        If Options = "EditData" Then
            Me.Text = "Edit Data"
            showInputs()
        End If
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You are supposed to set the `DateTimePicker`'s `Value` property like you did at first, **but** you shouldn't enter the value as a string... Instead parse it to a [**`DateTime` structure**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
Dim ResultDate As DateTime
If DateTime.TryParse(ExpiryDate, ResultDate) = True Then
    DateTimePicker2_ExpDt.Value = ResultDate
Else
    'Do what you want when 'ExpiryDate' could not be parsed into a DateTime object.
End If
```

Comment: It worked but when I edit again, the DateTimePicker resets again.

Comment: I've discovered that every time I clear or reset the the DateTimePicker after closing the form it doesn't worked anymore.

Comment: @GuideMe : [Place a breakpoint](http://www.visual-basic-tutorials.com/beginner/Breakpoints.html) on the `DateTime.TryParse` line and tell me what the value of `ExpiryDate` is.

Comment: The logical error happen because of I cleared the DateTimePicker text after closing. When I click the edit again it won't accept the value anymore. The problem has been solved.

Comment: @GuideMe : So my answer did not really help in solving the problem then, because it was solved by fixing something else?